# Is it possible to mount READ/WRITE ext4 partition under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mount, ext4

I would like to have shared home directory (or it's subdirectory) under dual boot Windows/Linux. I know I can how to mount NTFS under Linux, but I don't like it has different file permissions. So, I would prefer reverse: mount ext4 under Windows. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I don't want to READ ext4 partition, I want to read it **AND WRITE**.

Documentation for newbies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions

Comment: Looks like third party tools are available for this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows. I tried searching up PowerShell solutions but couldn't find too much but someone else may know.

Comment: To mount read-only, use DiskInternals Linux Reader. However, I've found writing to ext[*n*] from Windows risky, sometimes damaging Linux.

Comment: @Run5k don't you mix r/o and r/w?

Comment: I've been looking for this too. There are plenty of third party tools available. I will not link them here as they can be easily found in google search. However I have not found any driver that would allow to mount ext FS **natively** (so that it can be accessed from windows explorer). At least not for windows 10. Keep an eye on [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) they have released great drivers before

Comment: I have a terrible workaround in mind but it may work: start a ubuntu server in virtualbox, try to mount the partition in this VM, then try to share the folder with the windows host.

Comment: @Dims is you read through the question that I referenced, you will see answers that specifically mention read **AND WRITE** (to utilize your own subtle emphasis).

Comment: @Run5k should I always read 10-page documents entitled "how to read something" hoping that there is also a hidden answer to question "how to write something"? Or you can be just more specific please?

Comment: @Dims, I see that you haven't changed very much.  Perhaps I was foolish to think that if you wanted an answer to your question, you would actually devote a minimal amount of effort to reading.  My mistake.  It will probably help you out a bit to dust off your remedial web browser skills and use `Ctrl + F` within your web browser to search for the word **write** within that question.